# how does typescript cast any[]

Tags: generics, typescript

I have a class

```
class List<T>
```

which contains:

```
private _items = [];


public items() {
    return this._items;
}
```

why does this work

```
private loop() {
    for (var x of this._items) {
    }
```

but this doesn't

```
 private loop() {
    for (var x of this.items) {
    }
```

with the error given as:
Type '() => any[]' is not an array type or a string type.

Answer (score 3):

You're just missing the method invocation on `this.items` - you want `this.items()` instead, which will return the array, rather than using the method itself as the target of iteration.

Comment: Oh my goodness you are right!  Stupid mistake.  I guess I'm still use to the C# days.

Comment: @MtnManChris that would happen in c# too ;) -- I think you are thinking about a get accessor: `public get items() { return this._items; }`

Comment: and that is exactly what I did, turned the items method into a get accessor